# Google Volley underscore in hostname

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-volley, google-http-client

I'm using the new **Volley** http stack from Google in my actual Android project. Everything went fine till i got a hostname with underscore in it (this is the well known bug of the java.net.URL when it ignores the hosname) Is there any known workaround for this error? Or any other library which can process it?

The exception is the following:

`com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException`

Thanks for advance!

Cheers,
Gabor

Comment: Try dropping in OkHTTP and using it as the underlying engine for Volley (https://plus.google.com/108284392618554783657/posts/eJJxhkTQ4yU) and see if OkHTTP has fixed this.

Comment: unfortunately it did not solved. the same problem exist, because the OkHTTPStack used java.net.URL.

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: have you tried using URLEncoder to encode the hostname where bad characters may exist?